# refreshClusters on esri.Cluster.featureLayer

Tags: leaflet, esri-leaflet

I am trying to 'refresh' a cluster layer which is created by L.esri.Cluster.featureLayer and a feature url. I have tried to remove and re-add the layer (with no succees). But the refreshClusters is not a function of a featureLayer, nor of a cluster.featureLayer.

Someone could explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

Since `L.esri.Cluster.FeatureLayer` extends [`L.esri.FeatureLayer`](http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/feature-layer.html) it most certainly has a `refresh()` method.

If you clear the network traffic in your browser and call the method in the console, you'll see a fresh set of queries go out to fetch new data.